# Who is this character in Loki?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, loki-2021

In Season 1, Episode 2 of *Loki*, we are finally shown the Variant that has been creating trouble for the TVA in the Sacred Timeline. Who is this character supposed to be?

> [image]

Comment: Lok-She! (Maybe that won't catch on.)

Comment: The audio description lady says that she's "*a mysterious blonde woman wearing Loki horns"*

Comment: That is a female Loki. In the Mythology Loki once turned into a Horse and **mothered** Sleipnir, Odins 8-legged horse. So, expect a horse Loki sooner rather then later :D

Comment: Loki Laufeydottir!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Within the show, it's been repeatedly stated that she's a variant of Loki.

> MOBIUS: Here's the deal. When we get out on the branch, we're not just looking for a Time Criminal. **We're looking for a Loki. A variation of this guy.** A type we should all be very familiar with, because the TVA has pruned a lotta these guys, almost more than any other Variant. And no two are alike. Slight differences in appearances, or not so slight. Different powers, although, powers, generally include shape-shifting, illusion-projection, and my favorite...
>
> <sub>*Loki* - S01E02 - "The Variant"</sub>

> LOKI: **Have any of you met a woman Variant of us?**
>
> CLASSIC LOKI: Sounds terrifying.
>
> LOKI: Oh, she is. But that's kind of what's great about her. She's different. She's not trying to take over the TVA, she's trying to take it down.
>
> <sub>*Loki* - S01E05 - "Journey Into Mystery"</sub>

This has been confirmed to be true, both by the actress playing the character, Sophia Di Martino, and by the director of *Loki* Season 1, Kate Herron.

> SOPHIA DI MARTINO: I think the story we're telling isn't necessarily about genderfluidity, but that **Sylvie is a variant of Loki**, but she's Sylvie, a character and a person in her own right.
>
> <sub>[SYLVIE ISN'T JUST "LADY LOKI," SOPHIA DI MARTINO TELLS INVERSE](https://www.inverse.com/entertainment/lokis-sophia-di-martino-says-sylvie-isnt-just-lady-loki)</sub>

> KATE HERRON: The main thing I would say is: Lady Loki in the comics is a very different character to our character, obviously. I love that character and I think she's got a very different journey. But our **Sylvie is a female Loki**, in that sense -- because in episode 1 and 2, they know it's a Loki they're tracking -- but I think that's part of the discussion. It's almost like Loki -- as in Tom Loki -- he's like, "Wait, how much of my life have you got? Who are you?" And I think that's the real question is, who is she? So, we will discuss that as the show goes on. Why does she not like being called Loki? What's her past? Where did she come from?
>
> <sub>['Loki' Director Talks Loki Being Bisexual, Sylvie's Comic Origins and That Cliffhanger (Exclusive)](https://www.etonline.com/loki-director-talks-loki-being-bisexual-sylvies-comic-origins-and-that-cliffhanger-exclusive-167929)</sub>

She doesn't like to be called 'Loki' anymore though, and currently goes by the alias 'Sylvie.'

> LOKI: All right, well... Slow down, Variant.
>
> SYLVIE: What part of imminent death confuses you? And don't call me "Variant."
>
> LOKI: **I'm sorry, but I'm not calling some faded photocopy of me "Loki."**
>
> SYLVIE: **Good. 'Cause that's not who I am anymore. I'm Sylvie now.**
>
> LOKI: **You changed your name. Brilliant.**
>
> SYLVIE: **It's called an alias.**
>
> <sub>*Loki* - S01E03 - "Lamentis"</sub>

She said she was *born* a goddess, which implies that she was born female, rather than being born male and then changing her sex.

> SYLVIE: I remember Asgard. Not much, but I remember. My home, my people, my life. The universe wants to break free, so it manifests chaos. **Like me being born the Goddess of Mischief.**
>
> <sub>*Loki* - S01E04 - "The Nexus Event"</sub>

The bits and pieces of info we've been given about her background suggest that -- like Hiddleston's Loki -- she was born on [Jotunheim](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Jotunheim) as the biological offspring of the Frost Giant, [Laufey](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Laufey), before being adopted and raised by Odin and Frigga on Asgard.

She certainly *told* Hiddleston's Loki that she was adopted...

> SYLVIE: Are you sure she was your mother?
>
> LOKI: Oh, no, she's not actually. I was adopted. Is that a bit of a spoiler for you? Sorry about that.
>
> SYLVIE: **No, I knew I was adopted.**
>
> LOKI: What? They told you?
>
> SYLVIE: Yeah. Did they not tell you?
>
> LOKI: No. I mean, they did, eventually.
>
> <sub>*Loki* - S01E03 - "Lamentis"</sub>

... and around the 20-minute mark in *Loki* S01E02, we briefly see a TVA file with the name 'Sylvie Laufeydottir' printed on it. ['Laufeydottir' translates from Norwegian to English as 'Laufey's daughter'](https://www.behindthename.com/glossary/view/scandinavian_names).

> [image]
>
> <sub>*Loki* - S01E02 - "The Variant"</sub>

Speaking of the TVA, we saw in *Loki* S01E04 that that a group of [Minutemen](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Minutemen) (led by [Ravonna Renslayer](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Ravonna_Renslayer)) kidnapped Sylvie from Asgard when she was a child, and [reset her timeline](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Reset_Charge). She managed to escape not long afterwards, by stealing Renslayer's [TemPad](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/TemPad), and has been a fugitive from the TVA ever since.

> SYLVIE: I remember Asgard. Not much, but I remember. My home, my people, my life. The universe wants to break free, so it manifests chaos. Like me being born the Goddess of Mischief. And as soon as that created a big enough detour from the Sacred Timeline, the TVA showed up, erased my reality, and took me prisoner. I was just a child. I escaped. Stole a TemPad and I ran for a long, long time, which really sucked. Everywhere and every-when I went, it caused a nexus event. Sent up a smoke flare. Because I'm not supposed to exist. Until, eventually, I figured out where to hide. And so that's where I grew up, the ends of a thousand worlds.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*Loki* - S01E04 - "The Nexus Event"</sub>

As you can see in the image above, Sylvie was shown to have dark hair as a child. Kate Herron confirmed that her blonde hair as an adult is a product of hair dye.

> KATE HERRON: I would say there's more to be delved into. One thing I would say is, like, she's different to the comics. Like, she's a unique character, but obviously, there's things that have been pulled from. I think for her character, she's on the run and she's called Sylvie and **she's dyed her hair. The blonde that we associate with Sylvie is played in that sense,** but it makes sense for her character within our story. But I would say deeper than that, yeah, there's more to be revealed about her character to comes.
>
> <sub>'Loki' Director Talks Loki Being Bisexual, Sylvie's Comic Origins and That Cliffhanger (Exclusive)</sub>

In regard to whether or not Sylvie is based on any existing comicbook characters, Sophia Di Martino has stated that Sylvie is her own character, with a new backstory.

> SOPHIA DI MARTINO: The character is Sylvie and she's her own character. The show is inspired by the comics and by lots of different things in the comics, but our story is a brand new story and a new backstory for Sylvie.
>
> <sub>[Sylvie Actor Responds To Lady Loki & Enchantress Theories](https://screenrant.com/lady-loki-sylvie-enchantress-theories-sophia-di-martino-response/)</sub>

That said, the basic *idea* of having a female Loki variant is almost certainly inspired by the female Loki from the comics, informally known as 'Lady Loki.' In particular, Sylvie bears a strong visual resemblance to Lady Loki's depiction within the *[Loki: Agent of Asgard](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Loki:_Agent_of_Asgard_Vol_1)* series.

> [image]
>
> <sub>*[Loki: Agent of Asgard #16](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Loki:_Agent_of_Asgard_Vol_1_16)* (September, 2015)</sub>

The name 'Sylvie' might've been borrowed from [Sylvie Lushton](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Sylvie_Lushton_(Earth-616)), a human granted powers by Loki in the comics.

> [image]
>
> <sub>*[Illuminati #5](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Illuminati_Vol_1_5)* (May, 2016)</sub>

Comment: It says her name "Sylvie Lauffidottir" on the TVA dossier Loki reads before they go to the superstore.

Comment: Supposedly she's credited as Sylvie rather than as the Variant in the Spanish dub: https://twitter.com/ashelynx22/status/1405075042438991873

Comment: @Derek - There is speculation that the MCU writers might've chosen to fuse elements of Sylvie Lushton and the female Loki into an entirely new character. The name, Lauffidottir, is suspiciously similar to Loki's last name, Laufeyson.

Comment: Yes, because it's a variant of Loki...

Comment: Looks like the Norse suffix -dottir for daughter, as opposed to -son for son. Loki's sister?

Comment: Would this make her the first [Rule 63](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_63) character to officially appear in the MCU?  I know we have a female Thor and Hulk coming at some point, and we had a couple female Spider-Beings (though *Into the Spiderverse* might not technically qualify as canon in the MCU).

Comment: @Darrel Hoffman - We've already seen gender-swapped characters in the MCU, such as the Ancient One, who was male in the comics. As far as I know though, this would be the first time we've seen male _and_ female versions of the same character within the MCU. My understanding is that _Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse_, as a Sony Pictures production, is **not** canon to the MCU.

Comment: Yeah, if you count the Ancient One, then technically the first Captain Marvel was male as well (Mar-Vell, not Shazam, that's a different universe), but I think she's been canonically female in the comics for far longer.  So yeah, I was referring specifically to characters that have appeared as both genders within the MCU.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman If I'm remembering correctly we've not seen any variants of a character before _Loki_. So if we're ever going to see any character that shows up as male and female in the MCU it's only going to be from now onwards. And of course as mentioned Into the Spider-Verse is not set in the MCU.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Well, there have certainly been variants, just not different gendered ones.  Thanos, Nebula, and Gamora (and everyone else in his army) in *Endgame* would qualify, for example.  So would Cap after he travels back to be with Peggy.  Evidently the Time Keepers were okay with that though...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman well here’s where terminology is important. Those aren’t Variants as described in Loki. Those are time travel duplicates really.

Answer (score 15):

She is, as confirmed by Tom Hiddleston, a variant of Loki.

> **Can you talk about working with Sophia Di Martino? Since she’s playing essentially a version of you, is there anything she borrows from your portrayal, and what are the odds that there’s some kind of deeper relationship between you two? Because I feel like it would be pretty interesting if the one person that Loki falls in love with is a version of himself.**
>
> **TH:** *That would be interesting. **I think the idea, it seemed so rich that Loki would be confronted with himself.** Not maybe just in a metaphorical way, but in a physical externalization. I absolutely loved working with Sophia. She had lots of questions for me, and my experience of playing the character, and various things that I had found interesting in the long history that the character has been around in human consciousness. But what was so wonderful is that she authored her own character completely. She had all her own ideas and inhabited it in her own way. Then the joy was putting the two of them together and seeing how they react to each other. Yeah, there’s lots of opportunities in there.*
>
> <sub><sup>[‘Loki’ Star Tom Hiddleston Discusses Sophia Di Martino’s Surprising and Mysterious Series Debut](https://www.slashfilm.com/tom-hiddleston-talks-lady-loki-introduction-and-sophia-di-martino/)</sup></sub>

Comment: It's somehow *incredibly* Loki for Loki to be very enthused about talking to themself.

Comment: Can Loki regenerate into female?

Comment: It's also possible that she's just some random person who was in the store, customer, employee, etc. - alt-Loki was trying on several different bodies just prior to that in the episode, maybe he just decided he liked this one and decided to keep her, using Loki's already-established illusion powers to alter her outfit to that whole green/gold horned armor getup he likes.  (This of course brings up all kinds of questions about gender-identity - does a person who can look like literally anyone at will even need to pick a single identity?  He/she could be anyone they want to be...)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, Identity isn't the half of it. Remember that in the Eddas Loki is Sleipnir's mother, and also considering the various forms of 'his' other children, this probably says Loki is fairly free and easy not just with sex but species as well.